# Codename One Push Notification

Tags: netbeans, push-notification, codenameone

We are trying to implement Push notification on one of our apps.

For Andriod, we registered with Firebase, downloaded the google-services.json file and added it to our native/andriod directory.

On the Emulator everything works fine, but on an Andriod device the Push Registration fails with Error code 0, INVALID_PARAMETERS as given by the pushRegistrationError callback method.

For iOS, we are trying to generate the Push Certificates using the iOS Certificate wizard on the Codename One Plugin for Netbeans. 
On the step where you should select Enable Push, the tick is unavailable.

[image]

We have upgraded to the Professional Subscription so the little note of Pro Feature Only is a bit weird.

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to login again in Codename One Settings for this to work, notice your email account and pro level should appear in the Codename One Settings UI. If they don't you might be running into a known bug for which we have a fix. We will release an update to the Codename One Settings app this Friday with the fix for that bug.

Comment: Thanks Shai, I think we are hitting that bug. We even tried changing our account password to force our dev environment to re-prompt for the details but it still showed as Basic on the Codename One Settings UI.

Comment: So this is probably that bug, we'll push the fix on Friday. When you send a build this should update the libraries and the settings UI